# Creating a set of (possibly many) posterior distributions iteratively using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, bayesian

The basic question is: how do I create a new, empty data.table, using the values in one column of an existing data.table as column names? So from this:

```
    set.seed(1)
    DT = data.table(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), y=runif(6),key="x")
    > DT 
       x         y
    1: a 0.2655087
    2: b 0.3721239
    3: c 0.5728534
    4: d 0.9082078
    5: e 0.2016819
    6: f 0.8983897
```

I want to automate creation of a data.table that looks like this (with numeric columns):

```
    > POST
    Empty data.table (0 rows) of 6 cols: a,b,c,d,e,f
```

To put the question in the context of the title: the characters in DT[,x] represent individuals; the values in DT[,y] are the posterior parameter estimates for the current iteration. I organised it this way because it seems to be quick and straightforward running calculations per row (calculating likelihoods, accepting/rejecting updated values and so on).

However, I want to store the values in y as a new row in another table (individuals (x) as columns, values (y) for each iteration in one row). This helps downstream, e.g. making it straightforward to create a mcmc object.

The primary problem is that I don't know how to automate the creation of an empty data.table to hold the posterior distribution, with the values in DT[,x] as column names. I want it to look like this before the first iteration:

```
    POST<-data.table(a=numeric(0),b=numeric(0),c=numeric(0),
    d=numeric(0),e=numeric(0),f=numeric(0))
    > POST
    Empty data.table (0 rows) of 6 cols: a,b,c,d,e,f
```

But I may have many individuals and I want to automate the conversion of column x in DT into column names for POST. Any suggestions?

To append the new values of DT[,y] to POST each iteration, this seems to work:

```
    setkey(DT,x)
    POST<-rbind(POST,data.table(t(DT[,.(y)])),use.names=FALSE)
```

To summarize, the whole thing should look something like this:

```
    #Table used for calculations, with initial values#
    set.seed(1)
    DT = data.table(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), y=runif(6),key="x")
    #Table for storing posterior (*automate*)#
    POST<-data.table(a=numeric(0),b=numeric(0),c=numeric(0),
    d=numeric(0),e=numeric(0),f=numeric(0))

    #for loop
   #Modify values of y, then:
   setkey(DT,x)
   POST<-rbind(POST,data.table(t(DT[,.(y)])),use.names=FALSE)
```

EDIT: based on Colonel Beauvel's response, I now have this, which produces what I want, but I haven't figured out yet how to paste in the name for the new list element on each iteration:

```
#Create a list outside the loop
POST<- list()

#For loop
#First iteration:
    POST$1<-data.table(t(DT[,y]));setattr(
    POST$1, 'names', DT[,x])
#Second iteration:
    POST$2<-data.table(t(DT[,y]));setattr(
    POST$2, 'names', DT[,x])

#End of loop
> rbindlist(POST, use.names=TRUE)
           a         b         c         d         e         f
1: 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
2: 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
```

(Ignore that the numbers are the same in each row - this is doing what I want).

Comment: what is the function you apply in the loop?

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel Thanks for your answer, it helped me produce something that works (although no doubt the syntax can still be improved), which I've detailed as an Answer. I don't know what convention is, but I prefer not to give specific details of the function. It's a several-step process and initially involves a larger (long form) data.table with many rows per individual (there is only one parameter being estimated per individual, but it's based on the values of a large number of variables).

Answer (score 1):

The objective is to store a set of accepted parameter values in the posterior distribution each iteration of a Bayesian analysis, and hence create an object containing the full posterior distribution of a potentially large number of independent parameters. Likelihood calculations and acceptance/rejection are done by row for efficiency (there are several steps, not specified here), then the results stored in columns:

```
#x contains individual reference numbers, y contains the parameter estimate.
#Initial values:
set.seed(1)
DT = data.table(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), y=runif(6),key="x")
> DT 
  x         y
1: a 0.7581031
2: b 0.7244989
3: c 0.9437248
4: d 0.5476466
5: e 0.7117439
6: f 0.3889051

#Create a list object to store the posterior
POST<-list()

#For loop
for(k in 1:10){
#After various calculations, DT has a new set of accepted posterior values.
#Just as a fake example:
DT[,y:=runif(6)]
#Add these to POST.
setkey(DT,x)
POST[[k]]<-data.table(t(DT[,y]));setattr(POST[[k]], 'names', DT[,x])
}#End of loop

#Create a mcmc object from the set of posterior distributions.
require(coda)
POST<-mcmc(rbindlist(POST, use.names=TRUE))
> POST
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 10 
Thinning interval = 1 
               a          b         c         d          e          f
 [1,] 0.51116978 0.20754511 0.2286581 0.5957120 0.57487220 0.07706438
 [2,] 0.03554058 0.64279549 0.9286152 0.5980924 0.56090075 0.52602772
 [3,] 0.98509522 0.50764182 0.6827881 0.6015412 0.23886868 0.25816593
 [4,] 0.72930962 0.45257083 0.1751268 0.7466983 0.10498764 0.86454495
 [5,] 0.61464497 0.55715954 0.3287773 0.4531314 0.50044097 0.18086636
 [6,] 0.52963060 0.07527575 0.2777559 0.2126995 0.28479048 0.89509410
 [7,] 0.44623532 0.77998489 0.8806190 0.4131242 0.06380848 0.33548749
 [8,] 0.72372595 0.33761533 0.6304141 0.8406146 0.85613166 0.39135928
 [9,] 0.38049389 0.89544543 0.6443158 0.7410786 0.60530345 0.90308161
 [10,] 0.29373016 0.19126011 0.8864509 0.5033395 0.87705754 0.18919362
```